# HTML text background-color not working with <span>

Tags: html, background-color

I'm having black text appear instead of the colored text I expect to appear. I'm using Chrome as my browser. Here's the line that isn't working:

```
<ul class="line-legend">
  <li>
    <span style="background-color:rgba(220,0,0,1)">
    </span>
    one
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="background-color:rgba(0,0,220,1)">
    </span>
    two
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's how it appears:

one

two

I'm very new to HTML.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text isn't inside the `span`, a nice identation should help you to identify when something like that happens.
Change it to the following:

```
<ul class="line-legend">
    <li>
        <span style="background-color: rgba(220,0,0,1)">one</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="background-color:rgba(0,0,220,1)">two</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this write your text in inside `span`

```
<ul class="line-legend"><li><span style="background-color:rgba(220,0,0,1); ">one</span></li><li><span style="background-color:rgba(0,0,220,1)">two</span></li></ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ns6jnhgv/)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using span so that you want different color for list style and text color so can use this solution for that

you can use `pseudo` css for styling the list styles which will not effect the `li` styles and you can give any style for the `li` like i have done

i have changed my list style color to `green` and background for li in different color

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbmam1vj/1/)

```css
ul.line-legend {
  list-style: none;
}
.line-legend li {
  position: relative;
}
.line-legend li:before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: green;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -19px
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="line-legend">
  <li class="red">one</li>
  <li class="blue">two</li>
</ul>
```